# AutoCompleteTextView for ListView with two type preview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I have one listview with AutoCompleteTextView. For list view I create adapter which has type like complex object. This adapter implements Filterable. All is ok. But I want to show filter results like list consists from one property of complex object.

```
private class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Request> implements
            Filterable {
        private Context context;
        private int resourceId;
        private List<Request> listOrders;
        private List<Request> mOriginalValues;
        private ListFilter listFilter;

        public OrderAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Request> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            this.context = context;
            this.resourceId = resource;
            this.listOrders = objects;
            this.mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<Request>(listOrders);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listOrders.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Request getItem(int pos) {
            return listOrders.get(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

            Request request = listOrders.get(position);

            TextView clientName = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.client_name);
            clientName.setText(request.getClientName());

            TextView opportunityNumber = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.opportunity_number);
            opportunityNumber.setText(request.getOpportunity()
                    .getOpportunityNumber());

            TextView detailedDescription = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.product_desc);
            detailedDescription.setText(request.getProjectDescription());

            TextView ownerName = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.requester);
            ownerName.setText(request.getOpportunity().getOpportunityOwner());

            TextView lastModifiedDate = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.last_modified_date_opportunity);
            lastModifiedDate.setText(DateTimeConverter.convertDateToString(
                    request.getOpportunity().getModifiedDate(), context
                    .getResources().getString(R.string.date_format)));

            return rowView;
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            if (listFilter == null) {
                listFilter = new ListFilter();
            }
            return listFilter;
        }

        private class ListFilter extends Filter {
            private Object lock;

            @Override
            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object order) {
                return ((Request) order).getClientName();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<Request>(listOrders);
                    }
                }

                if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                    List<Request> list = new ArrayList<Request>(mOriginalValues);
                    filterResults.values = list;
                    filterResults.count = list.size();
                } else {
                    String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();
                    List<Request> values = new ArrayList<Request>(
                            mOriginalValues);
                    int count = values.size();

                    List<Request> filteredValues = new ArrayList<Request>(count);
                    for (Request request : values) {
                        if (request.getOpportunity().getOpportunityNumber()
                                .toLowerCase().contains(prefixString)
                                || request.getClientName().toLowerCase()
                                .contains(prefixString)) {
                            filteredValues.add(request);
                        }
                    }
                    filterResults.values = filteredValues;
                    filterResults.count = filteredValues.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence filterString,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                List<Request> values = (ArrayList<Request>) results.values;
                if (!values.isEmpty()) {
                    listOrders = values;
                } else {
                    listOrders = new ArrayList<Request>();
                }

                if (results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Should I have 2 type adapter or exist another way do that?

Comment: what exactly to you want to achieve ?

Comment: add your adapter class code

Comment: @TomerMor I want that the same list view contains 2 type of presentation (extended and short).

Answer (score 1):

You can use one adapter,

in order to support more then one view type you need to override two methods in the adapter:

1.`getViewTypeCount`
2.`getItemViewType`

example :

```
    /**
     * Indicates how many view types this adapter support. two types - incoming and outgoing view
         */
        private final static int NUM_VIEW_TYPE = 2;
        private final static int VIEW_INCOMING = 0;
        private final static int VIEW_OUTGOING = 1;

        private static final String TAG = "ConversationAdapter";

        public ConversationAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int threadId) {
            super(context, c, 0);
            this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mThreadId = threadId;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return NUM_VIEW_TYPE;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            Cursor c = (Cursor) getItem(position);
            int itemType = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Sms.TYPE));
            return (itemType == 1 ? VIEW_INCOMING : VIEW_OUTGOING);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            int viewType = getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());

            View RowView = (viewType == VIEW_INCOMING) ? inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.conversation_item_received, parent, false) : inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.conversation_item_sent, parent, false);

            final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textBody = (TextView) RowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.conversation_item_body);
            holder.textDate = (TextView) RowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.conversation_item_date);
            holder.imageType = (ImageView) RowView.findViewById(R.id.img_type);
            RowView.setTag(holder);
            return RowView;
        }
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}
```

Comment: Maybe, it isn't what I want. I want to change type of view not against from some type of property but for displaying filter results in short form (it means from an event like 'calling performFiltering')

Comment: you can set a flag in newView  isCalledFromPreforFilter  and then inflate other layout,  and also in the function performFiltering call notifyDataSetChanged